# SearchController in iOS 11. Can't touch in any tableView cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchcontroller

System behavior of the search controller:

- Go to iPhone settings
- Slide to show searchBar
- Tap on searchBar
- TableView has gray color now and if I touch anywhere (not in searchBar) searchBar will hide
- I enter any text and tableView has normal color now, I can click into any of searched cells.

In my application, after tapped any text tableView is still gray. I can't tap in any of searched cells.
The difference is also that when I searching I update old tableView (I don't have different tableView after searching) by using `updateSearchResultsForSearchController` and reloadData after that.

The question is how to hide this gray view and give chance to tap on cells after enter any text in searchcontroller?

The way I create search controller:

```
UISearchController * search = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
search.searchResultsUpdater = self;
self.navigationItem.searchController = search;
self.navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = YES;
self.navigationItem.searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
self.navigationItem.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
```

and how I update tableView cells:

```
- (void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {
    self.actualSearchController = searchController;
    self.filteredData = [self filterContentForSearchText:searchController.searchBar.text];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (NSMutableArray<MySectionContainter *> *)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString *)text {
    NSMutableArray<MySectionContainter *> *sections = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (MySectionContainter *section in self.tableData) {
        NSArray *objects = [sectionInfo.rowObjects filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[self.filterSource predicateForSearching:text]];

        if ([objects count] > 0) {
            [sections addObject:[[MySectionContainter alloc] initWithTitle:section.title andObjects:objects]];
        }
    }

    return sections;
}

- (NSPredicate *)predicateForSearching:(NSString *)text {
    return [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id  _Nullable evaluatedObject, NSDictionary<NSString *,id> * _Nullable bindings) {
        if ([evaluatedObject isKindOfClass:[MyClass class]]) {
            return [((MyClass *)evaluatedObject).title containsString:text];
        }


    return NO;
    }];
}
```

Example project code: https://pastebin.com/m9V2dunB

Screenshot:

[image]

System behavior:

[image]

Test project:
https://www.sendspace.com/file/2lhedj

Comment: @Tubelight Nothing has changed.

Comment: pls share you screenshot so, i'll clarify what you want for this?

Comment: @Tubelight I have the same situation like in fourth point (in system search on settings) but also after putting text. I will prepare and share screenshot.

Comment: @Tubelight I added screenshot. I needed create new project and add tableView and searchBar in the same way.

Comment: @Tubelight I added example code also.

Comment: @Tubelight This link is not helpful. I don't have problem with setting any color. My problem is: I can't click on any cell. I am unable to do that while searching.

Comment: @Tubelight I added screenshot of system behavior. Is different - I can tap on any searched cell.

Comment: @PiotrWasilewicz i checked you demo project and can tap on any cell. It logs `sth` each time i tap on cell. Is there anything wrong here?

Comment: @trungduc But are you doing it after putting some text to searchController? What I do: I slide to show searchBar, write "a", only some cells are visible now, and now I want to tap on any cell. This time (this one time) I don't have "sth" in logs. Instead of it searchBar is hiding. Video: https://www.sendspace.com/file/ei0ukw

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solve problem in your demo project by adding this line to `viewDidLoad`

`search.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;`

Just remove dim background of `UISearchController`, everything will work fine.

Comment: You saved my tomorrow day. It is working, thank you!

Comment: Welcome my friend @PiotrWasilewicz ;)

Comment: Not at all obvious, wasn't able to access my scope buttons until I set this value - you've saved me some hair - thanks

Comment: @Nostradamus I'm glad to hear that. God bless your hair (づ｡◕‿‿◕｡)づ

Comment: For iOS 12 and later, use:

     search.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;

Answer (score 0):

You can set selection property of tableview from interface builder. Select your tableview in XIB or Storyboard then select attribute inspector and set single selectiontoselection` property like below screenshot.

[image]

Remove this line in your code:

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

Comment: I tried this code. It didn't change anything. Still unable to click in cell while searching.

Comment: are you sure to used like this tabview method selectRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: changing it also not helped. "selectRowAtIndexPath" is not calling while searching.

Comment: I added link to my test project. Please run it if you can.

Comment: Remove this below line in your code:
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

Comment: I removed this line. Nothing has changed.

Comment: sorry, glad you found an answer anyway!

Comment: I didn't find yet. Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to dismiss the controller after making a selection, so this is what I did:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    // 1. Dismiss search controller
    searchController.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)

    let record = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)
    delegate?.didSelectUser(record)
    // 2. Dismiss the UITableViewController
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```